# Link on option value

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem to insert a jump link into this option value:

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:300px;">
  <option value='ad' data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag ad" data-title="Andorra">Andorra</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open a link when clicking on the option? Then this should do the job:

```
<html>
<body>
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:300px;">
  <option value='ad' data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" onclick="location='http://www.example.com';" data-imagecss="flag ad" data-title="Andorra">Andorra</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im not sure what im doing wrong here. I tried with your link but i can't get it to work as it should. You sure that is right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to opening a link when clicking the option:

I placed the dropdown bar inside of a form tag. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgmef9y4/

Code:

```
<form>
<select name="URL" id="countries" style="width:300px;" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="#">Choose your country</option>
    <option value="andorra.html">Andorra</option>
</select>
</form>
```

When you click the dropdown and choose "Andorra", the page will open the link andorra.html (which obviously leads to a 404 -- as there is no andorra.html page on jsfiddle.net).